# Condition check with LEFT function

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following sample data:

```
create table num_test
(
    numb int,
    names varchar(20)
);

insert into num_test values(123456,'ABC');
insert into num_test values(12345,'DCD');
insert into num_test values(1234567,'ECD');
insert into num_test values(123456789,'BCD');
```

I have the input value:

```
declare @num int = 123456
```

I want to search for `left` 6 or 5 integers. If match with `left 6` the `left 5` should be ignored else `left 5` should show.

So the expected result should be:

```
numb    names
-----------------
123456  ABC
```

Query:

```
declare @num int = 123456

SELECT * FROM num_test 
where numb = LEFT(@num,6) or numb = LEFT(@num,5)
```

Comment: where numb = @num

Comment: Rows 1,3 and 4 would match to LEFT(6) though, so which one would you want to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could order the results by the length of `numb` and take the top one:

```
SELECT   TOP 1 * 
FROM     num_test 
WHERE    numb IN (LEFT(@num,6), LEFT(@num,5))
ORDER BY LEN(numb) DESC
```